# OpenCV CUDA SURF Performance vs CPU version

Tags: opencv, sift, gpu, surf

I am trying to process a number of images to find if they are side by side stereopairs. First step uses SURF to find matches between left and right halfs of an image. The difference between CPU and GPU implementation speed seems to be rather small. What might be the reason? Here is a code for testing and test image: [photo.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em7k9.jpg)

```py
import cv2 as cv
import time

print('OpenCV Version', cv.__version__)

surfCPU = cv.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(300, nOctaveLayers=2)
surfGPU = cv.cuda.SURF_CUDA_create(300,_nOctaveLayers=2)
matcherCPU = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_L2)
matcherGPU = cv.cuda.DescriptorMatcher_createBFMatcher(cv.NORM_L2)

resize_width = 1024

def getMatches(img, useCPU):
    height, width = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
    
    w_percent = resize_width / width
    height = int(height * w_percent)
    width = resize_width
    
    if useCPU:
        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv.resize(img,(width, height),
                        interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
        
        gray_left = img[:,:width//2]
        gray_right = img[:,width//2:]
        
        kp1, des1 = surfCPU.detectAndCompute(gray_left,None)
        kp2, des2 = surfCPU.detectAndCompute(gray_right,None)
        knn_matches = matcherCPU.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    else:
        gpu_img = cv.cuda_GpuMat(img)
        gpu_img = cv.cuda.resize(gpu_img, (width,height),
                                 interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
        
        gpu_gray = cv.cuda.cvtColor(gpu_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        gpu_gray_left = cv.cuda_GpuMat(gpu_gray, (0, 0, width//2, height))
        gpu_gray_right = cv.cuda_GpuMat(gpu_gray, (width//2, 0,width //2, height))
        
        kp1GPU, des1 = surfGPU.detectWithDescriptors(gpu_gray_left, None)
        kp2GPU, des2  = surfGPU.detectWithDescriptors(gpu_gray_right, None)
        knn_matches = matcherGPU.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
        kp1 = cv.cuda_SURF_CUDA.downloadKeypoints(surfGPU, kp1GPU)
        kp2 = cv.cuda_SURF_CUDA.downloadKeypoints(surfGPU, kp2GPU)

img = cv.imread('photo.jpg')

res = getMatches(img, False)
samples = 100

for testName in ['GPU', 'CPU']:
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(samples):
        getMatches(img, testName == 'CPU')
    print(testName,
          "time",
          str(int((time.time() - start_time) / samples * 1000)) + 'ms')
```

Output on my machine (Core i5 6500, GTX 750 Ti)

```
OpenCV Version 4.3.0
GPU time 32ms
CPU time 52ms
```

EDIT:
Here is an attempt at measuring times. Resizing image on CPU before uploading makes some difference though not dramatic:

```
- GPU (35ms)

upload            23%      8ms  |||||||||||
grayscale          6%      2ms  |||
resize (gpu)       1%      0ms  
crop               0%      0ms  
detect            65%     23ms  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
matcher            1%      0ms  
download           0%      0ms  



- GPU (26ms)

resize (cpu)       4%      1ms  ||
upload             1%      0ms  
grayscale          2%      0ms  |
crop               0%      0ms  
detect            88%     23ms  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
matcher            1%      0ms  
download           0%      0ms



- CPU (50ms)

grayscale          6%      3ms  |||
resize             2%      1ms  |
crop               0%      0ms  
detect            89%     45ms  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
matcher            2%      1ms  |
```

EDIT 2:

```
photo.jpg  downscaled 382 1024
GPU 24ms     |||||||||||||||||||||
CPU 57ms     ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

photo.jpg  1747 4674
GPU 436ms    |||||||||||||||
CPU 1412ms   ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

photo-large.jpg  downscaled 378 1024
GPU 31ms     |||||||||||||
CPU 116ms    ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

photo-large.jpg  2998 8105
GPU 5549ms   ||||
CPU 63278ms  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that 60-70% or so faster is a small speed difference. Also you need to consider what your own code generates as overhead plus the amount of parallelism that can actually be applied. The number of features also plays a role. The number of features also plays an important role. Try with a bigger image (2-4 times the size) and see what happens.

Comment: @rbaleksandar with bigger pictures time difference between GPU and CPU becomes more apparent (see edit)